# "Object" generating function in Lua

Tags: lua, meta-method

I use this to generate "class" in Lua.

```
function Class(...)
  local cls = {};
  local bases = {arg};
  for i, base in ipairs(bases) do
    for k, v in pairs(base) do
      cls[k] = v
    end
  end
  cls.__index = cls;
  cls._is_a =  {[cls] = true}
  for i, base in pairs(bases) do
    for c in pairs(base._is_a) do
      cls._is_a[c] = true
    end
    cls._is_a[base] = true
  end
  function cls.IsType(obj,cmptype)
    if cmptype then
      return obj._is_a[cmptype] or false;
    else
      if type(obj) == 'table' then
        return cls._is_a[obj.__index] or false;
      else
        return false;
      end
    end
  end
  cls._init = function() end;
  setmetatable(cls, {
    __call = function (c, ...)
      local instance = setmetatable({}, c)

      instance._init(instance, ...);
      return instance
    end
  })
  return cls
end
```

In zeroBane Studio this code launches, and i can do stuff like

```
Test1 = Class();
function Test1:_init()
end

Test2 = Class(Test1);

function Test2:_init()
  Test1._init(self);
end
```

But when i try to do something similar in Starbound, it will complain about  Test1._init(self); with message "attempt to index a function value". I can bet that it has to do with metatables, but i'm not good enough to solve it by myself. 
Is there a way to fix this, so that i will be able to call functions using '.'?

Comment: Replace `local bases = {arg}` with `local bases = {...}`

Comment: That's interesting, because If I do that It complains about 5th line - "for k, v in pairs(base) do" with this message "[11:15:17.282] [Error] Exception while creating lua context for scripts '('/Objects/Rack/digitalstorage_rack.lua')': (LuaException) Error code 2, [string "/Objects/Rack/digitalstorage_rack.lua"]:1: (LuaException) Error code 2, [string "/Classes/Class.lua"]:5: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got function)"

Comment: What is the value of `type(Test1)` just after `Test1 = Class();`?

Comment: `Drive = Class();
local t = type(Drive);
function  Drive:_init()
  LogDebug(type(Drive));
  LogDebug(t);
end`
This slightly modified copy-paste from my code, and both say that they Drive is table. LogDebug is just print with more features that i use in starbound.

Comment: However. for different class I included with require, type() returns function.

Comment: Probably, your "Drive" class was shadowed with a function having the same name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153531/discussion-between-user2463506-and-egor-skriptunoff).

Comment: You were right @egor-skriptunoff, I dont know how, but it really was overritten